# InApp purchases weird arranging in Array

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase

I am trying to do inaAppPurchases and using following code

```
     NSSet *myProductIdentifiers = [NSSet setWithObjects:
                                     @"inapppurchase.first",
                                     @"inapppurchase.second",
                                     @"inapppurchase.third",
                                     @"inapppurchase.fourth",
                                     @"inapppurchase.fifth",
                                     @"inapppurchase.sixth",
                                     nil];

        if ((self = [super initWithProductIdentifiers:myProductIdentifiers]))
        {

        }
        return self;
///////////////////////////////////    

    - (id)initWithProductIdentifiers:(NSSet *)identifiers
    {
        if ((self = [super init]))
        {
        }
        self.productIdentifiers = identifiers;

        return self;
    }

    - (void)requestProducts
    {
        self.request = [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:productIdentifiers];
        request.delegate = self;
        [request start];
    }

    - (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response
    {
        self.products = response.products;
        SKProduct *product = [self.products objectAtIndex:0];
        NSLog(@"%@", product.price);
        self.request = nil;
    }
```

The problem is, when i call `requestProducts` and then delegate function   `- (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response` is called, the order of products is different than my NSSet values

The order of my self.products is Fifth, First, second,Fourth, Sixth and third. 
Why is that?
Why is it not in proper order?

Comment: By definition, a set has no order. Perhaps an ordered set `NSOrderedSet` will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `NSSet` does not keep objects in a specific order, unlike arrays. In fact, `objectAtIndex` will not work with a `NSSet`. In order to view the objects in a `NSSet`, you can use one of its properties, such as `anyObject`, which randomly returns an object in the set, or `allObjects`, which returns a `NSArray` of all the objects in the set, with them ordered randomly in the returned array. The `SKProductsRequest` is likely accessing `NSSet.allObjects`, and then enumerates each object in the array to determine if it is a valid product.

Once you are returned your randomly ordered set of valid products, simply compare the set to an array that has the products properly ordered inside. You will be able to identify any invalid products, while retaining your product order.